# Unable to pass data from a Parent'state to a Child's state in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass an Array of values from a Parent module to a Child module, and set them in the Child's state in order to display a chart.

Here is my Parent module:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRates();
  }

  getRates = () => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.exchangerate.host/timeseries?start_date=2022-07-01&end_date=2022-07-05&base=USD&symbols=EUR"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((timeseries) => {
        const rates = Object.values(timeseries.rates);
        this.setState({
          data: rates,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const data = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Child data={data} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the Child module:

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      items: this.props.data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    console.log("Child data from state: ", items);
    console.log("Child data from props: ", this.props.data);
    return (
      <>
        <ReactApexChart options={items} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I am getting from the console.log():

Child data from state: `[]`

Child data from props: `(30) [95.9182, 95.7676, 94.8036, ..., 95.2308, 95.2906]`

Why am I unable to set the Child's state with this data?

Comment: What about the chart, is it getting rendered eventually?

Comment: I guess the value is not there yet, when componentDidMount(). add a console.log there. And look into `React.useEffect`, as it combines componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount.

Comment: are you sure you only get 1 time this `console.log`? since state is updated and `render` will run again, you should see another set of these 2 logs

Comment: @EnesToraman no the chart doesn't get rendered.

Comment: @Apostolos you are correct, I get these ```console.log``` a few times, each time they get rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Child component does not get its state updated because the lifecycle function you are using does not get called when the component gets an updated set of props from the Parent.

Please check the `Updating` heading on https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp

You will not find the `componentDidMount` lifecycle in there because it does not get called on a prop update.
What you need to use is something like `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    return {items: props.data};
}
```

This makes sure that every time the `Parent` sends an updated value in the props, the `Child` uses it to update the state and then re-render accordingly.